# I'm trying to access the list across an Entity Framework, dump me the error of integrated security

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I set up a test web site through which I will access the database, and browse content in the database, on the website I will see the table from the database.

I work in Visual Studio 2017, .NET Core Framework is 2.0, writing code is C# 7.1. I've been upgrading nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (2.2.2).

The application is using ASP.NET Core, the database is `Northwind` of Microsoft in SQL Server.

Note: I learn to program from the book: C# 7.1 and .NET Core 2.0 of Packt

When I try to access the list with the specified code

```
public class SuppliersModel : PageModel
{
    private Northwind db;

    public SuppliersModel(Northwind injectedContext)
    {
        db = injectedContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Suppliers { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
         ViewData["Title"] = "Northwind Web Site - Suppliers";
         Suppliers = db.Suppliers.Select(s => s.CompanyName).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary parsetable, string connectionString, bool buildChain, Dictionary synonyms, bool firstKey)
>   ...
>   NorthwindWeb.Pages.SuppliersModel.OnGet() in Suppliers.cshtml.cs
>       + Suppliers = db.Suppliers.Select(s => s.CompanyName).ToArray();

Comment: Please update your question with the full stack of your exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the `IEnumerable` as a string, when I think you mean to use a class.

Currently you are just declaring a list of string, which won’t have the property company name.

I think it should be

```
    IEnumerable<Supplier>
```

If the class was

```
   public class Supplier
   {
        public string ComapnyName
   }
```

To clarify further, when declaring an `IEnumerable` or list whatever you put in the <> is the type of object in the collection so by declaring an `IEnumerable` of string you can only have a list of strings and they won't have a property name, just like

```
"test"
"test2"
"etc"
```

by declaring an `IEnumerable` of supplier class it would be a list of that class like so

```
[0] Supplier.CompanyName = "ltd"
[1] Supplier.CompanyName = "PLC"
```

and you could reference in your code using

```
Suppliers[0].CompanyName
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a public class :

```
public class Supplier
{   
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string HomePage { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

}
```

and for connceto to server

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<Northwind>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"));
    }
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the error is based on what you posted. Can you update and post the exception you are getting? Make sure that the connection string used in your passed in `injectionContext` is correct and the `.cshtml` file is also handling the array properly. The code you posted here is fine, so it makes me suspect that there is a configuration error outside of this Model class.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you for your help, after I restarted Visual Studio, the problem is resolved.

Can I check in Visual Studio, what changes I did in the code?

Something like last edits?

The worst thing is that I do not know what I did, that the code worked.

Great help was your comments.